# Debian 64-bit sees less than 4GB of RAM

Tags: debian, virtualbox, memory

I have a Debian wheezy (7.4) amd64 virtual machine running under VirtualBox 4.3.10 on a Win7 x64 host with AMD A10-5700 processor.  The virtual machine is configured with 16GB of memory (the host has 32GB physical RAM, all of which appears to be recognized correctly).  No other VMs are running.  Nevertheless, the Debian VM sees far less RAM than allocated.

```
$ uname -a
Linux debian3 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       3610656     958788    2651868          0     181072     379744
-/+ buffers/cache:     397972    3212684
Swap:      3668988          0    3668988

$ dmesg | grep BIOS-e820
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000000000 - 00000000000a0000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000de9df000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000de9df000 - 00000000de9ec000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000de9ec000 - 00000000dfb6c000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000dfb6c000 - 00000000dfbc4000 (reserved)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000dfbc4000 - 00000000dfbcc000 (ACPI data)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000dfbcc000 - 00000000dfbd0000 (ACPI NVS)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000dfbd0000 - 00000000dffd0000 (usable)
[    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000dffd0000 - 00000000dfff0000 (reserved)
```

I do have VirtualBox set up to use EFI with this VM, so here are some possibly-relevant messages:

```
$ dmesg | grep EFI
[    0.000000] EFI v2.31 by EDK II
[    0.000000] Kernel-defined memdesc doesn't match the one from EFI!
[    0.000000] EFI: mem00: type=7, attr=0xf, range=[0x0000000000000000-0x00000000000a0000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem01: type=2, attr=0xf, range=[0x0000000000100000-0x00000000003b1000) (2MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem02: type=7, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000003b1000-0x0000000002000000) (28MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem03: type=4, attr=0xf, range=[0x0000000002000000-0x0000000002600000) (6MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem04: type=7, attr=0xf, range=[0x0000000002600000-0x0000000036bf8000) (837MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem05: type=2, attr=0xf, range=[0x0000000036bf8000-0x00000000375f4000) (9MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem06: type=7, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000375f4000-0x00000000a49a4000) (1747MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem07: type=2, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000a49a4000-0x00000000dc000000) (886MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem08: type=4, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000dc000000-0x00000000dc020000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem09: type=7, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000dc020000-0x00000000dddc3000) (29MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem10: type=4, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000dddc3000-0x00000000de1a6000) (3MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem11: type=7, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000de1a6000-0x00000000de440000) (2MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem12: type=1, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000de440000-0x00000000de45d000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem13: type=4, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000de45d000-0x00000000de9df000) (5MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem14: type=5, attr=0x800000000000000f, range=[0x00000000de9df000-0x00000000de9ec000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem15: type=4, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000de9ec000-0x00000000deaec000) (1MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem16: type=7, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000deaec000-0x00000000deb1f000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem17: type=2, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000deb1f000-0x00000000deb25000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem18: type=4, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000deb25000-0x00000000df9ec000) (14MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem19: type=7, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000df9ec000-0x00000000df9ef000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem20: type=3, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000df9ef000-0x00000000dfb6c000) (1MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem21: type=5, attr=0x800000000000000f, range=[0x00000000dfb6c000-0x00000000dfb9c000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem22: type=6, attr=0x800000000000000f, range=[0x00000000dfb9c000-0x00000000dfbc0000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem23: type=0, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000dfbc0000-0x00000000dfbc4000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem24: type=9, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000dfbc4000-0x00000000dfbcc000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem25: type=10, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000dfbcc000-0x00000000dfbd0000) (0MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem26: type=4, attr=0xf, range=[0x00000000dfbd0000-0x00000000dffd0000) (4MB)
[    0.000000] EFI: mem27: type=6, attr=0x800000000000000f, range=[0x00000000dffd0000-0x00000000dfff0000) (0MB)
[    1.204229] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    6.734371] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
```

And one other message (iommu-related) I'm pretty sure shouldn't be here:

```
$ dmesg | grep Calgary
[    0.000000] Calgary: detecting Calgary via BIOS EBDA area
[    0.000000] Calgary: Unable to locate Rio Grande table in EBDA - bailing!
```

The bootloader is `grub-efi-amd64`.  All the above output was from booting with this configuration from `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='(hd0,gpt2)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7d58d543-5c40-4e8d-bbfa-f3773dc7ca15
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=7d58d543-5c40-4e8d-bbfa-f3773dc7ca15 ro quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
}
```

I have looked at various parts of the kernel source and documentation, the VirtualBox documentation, and elsewhere for answers.  I have tried adding and removing various combinations of `mem=16G`, `iommu=soft`, `swiotlb=force`, `allowdac`, `noefi`, and `add_efi_memmap` without any real effect.  The `iommu=soft` parameter does eliminate the "Calgary"-related messages, as expected, but there is no effect on the reported memory.  Just for fun, I tried reducing the configured memory to 8GB, but that had no apparent effect either.  If it matters, I am running the stock kernel.

What else might work?

**Edit:**

Here is the output of `dmidecode`:

```
# dmidecode 2.11
# SMBIOS entry point at 0xdfbce000
SMBIOS 2.5 present.
10 structures occupying 449 bytes.
Table at 0xDFBCE020.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 20 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: innotek GmbH
    Version: VirtualBox
    Release Date: 12/01/2006
    Address: 0xE0000
    Runtime Size: 128 kB
    ROM Size: 128 kB
    Characteristics:
        ISA is supported
        PCI is supported
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: innotek GmbH
    Product Name: VirtualBox
    Version: 1.2
    Serial Number: 0
    UUID: 0B1BEC54-20D1-4809-A92D-22EE66339AA8
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: Not Specified
    Family: Virtual Machine

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation
    Product Name: VirtualBox
    Version: 1.2
    Serial Number: 0
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
    Location In Chassis: Not Specified
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 13 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: Oracle Corporation
    Type: Other
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: Not Specified
    Serial Number: Not Specified
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 126, 42 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 126, 15 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 126, 28 bytes
Inactive

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 11, 7 bytes
OEM Strings
    String 1: vboxVer_4.3.10
    String 2: vboxRev_93012

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 128, 8 bytes
OEM-specific Type
    Header and Data:
        80 08 08 00 35 C7 31 00

Handle 0xFEFF, DMI type 127, 4 bytes
End Of Table
```

Comment: The output of `dmidecode` (not in the default package list IIRC) might help.

Comment: @Gilles It doesn't say too much, but I'll add the output.